# Using precedence in Bison for unary minus doesn't solve shift/reduce conflict

Tags: grammar, bison, unary-operator, shift-reduce-conflict

I'm devising a very simple grammar, where I use the unary minus operand. However, I get a shift/reduce conflict. In the Bison manual, and everywhere else I look, it says that I should define a new token and give it higher precedence than the binary minus operand, and then use "%prec TOKEN" in the rule.

I've done that, but I still get the warning. Why?

I'm using bison (GNU Bison) 2.4.1. The grammar is shown below:

```
%{
#include <string>
extern "C" int yylex(void);
%}

%union {
    std::string token;
}

%token <token> T_IDENTIFIER T_NUMBER
%token T_EQUAL T_LPAREN T_RPAREN

%right T_EQUAL
%left T_PLUS T_MINUS
%left T_MUL T_DIV
%left UNARY

%start program

%%

program : statements expr
;

statements : '\n'
           | statements line
;

line : assignment
     | expr
;

assignment : T_IDENTIFIER T_EQUAL expr
;

expr : T_NUMBER
     | T_IDENTIFIER
     | expr T_PLUS expr
     | expr T_MINUS expr
     | expr T_MUL expr
     | expr T_DIV expr
     | T_MINUS expr   %prec UNARY
     | T_LPAREN expr T_RPAREN
;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`%prec` doesn't do as much as you might hope here. It tells Bison that in a situation where you have `- a * b` you want to parse this as `(- a) * b` instead of `- (a * b)`. In other words, here it will prefer the `UNARY` rule over the `T_MUL` rule. In either case, you can be certain that the `UNARY` rule will get applied eventually, and it is only a question of the order in which the input gets reduced to the unary argument.

In your grammar, things are very much different. Any sequence of `line` non-terminals will make up a `sequence`, and there is nothing to say that a `line` non-terminal must end at an end-of-line. In fact, any expression can be a `line`. So here are basically two ways to parse `a - b`: either as a single line with a binary minus, or as two “lines”, the second starting with a unary minus. There is nothing to decide which of these rules will apply, so the rule-based precedence won't work here yet.

Your solution is correcting your line splitting, by requiring every `line` to actually end with or be followed by an end-of-line symbol.

If you really want the behaviour your grammar indicates with respect to line endings, you'd need two separate non-terminals for expressions which can and which cannot start with a `T_MINUS`. You'd have to propagate this up the tree: the first `line` may start with a unary minus, but subsequent ones must not. Inside a parenthesis, starting with a minus would be all right again.

Comment: I forgot about this question because it "fixed" itself once I had added the actions. Although it shouldn't have mattered, it now worked and I didn't care much more about it. However, looking back at my grammar, I realize that I must have submitted an out-of-date version or something because a line _should_ end with a semicolon. I believe that I must have added those at some point when I added the actions, thus resolving the conflict. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

The expr rule is ok (without the %prec UNARY). Your shift/reduce conflict comes from the rule:

```
statements : '\n'
           | statements line
;
```

The rule does not what you think. For example you can write:

```
a + b c + d
```

I think that is not supposed to be valid input.

But also the program rule is not very sane:

```
program : statements expr
;
```

The rules should be something like:

```
program: lines;

lines: line | lines line;

line: statement "\n" | "\n";

statement: assignment | expr;
```