# Lex/Yacc Flex/Bison: Precedence on reusing tokens for multiple production rules

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex

I am making a simple compiler for expressions, however I am stuck figuring out how to use Bison's precedence keywords

In my lexer I define the following check:

```
'-'     {ECHO;return(MINUS);}
```

However, I noticed that when evaluating expressions, '-' can have two meanings, 1) for subtraction and 2) for negation of an number, and both have different precedences.

In my parser file how would I account for this by using %left and %right to define associativity?

I know I can do

```
%left PLUS
%left MINUS
... and so on
```

For each such token, but since negation has right associativity and higher precedence, how would I include that in here, since I do not think I can do

```
%left PLUS
%left MINUS
%right MINUS /* This is the negation one */
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772504/using-precedence-in-bison-for-unary-minus-doesnt-solve-shift-reduce-conflict
?

Comment: No I didn't see that, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/yacc/:

> [...] unary operators must, in general, be given a precedence. Sometimes a unary operator and a binary operator have the same symbolic representation, but different precedences. An example is unary and binary '-'; unary minus may be given the same strength as multiplication, or even higher, while binary minus has a lower strength than multiplication. The keyword, %prec, changes the precedence level associated with a particular grammar rule. %prec appears immediately after the body of the grammar rule, before the action or closing semicolon, and is followed by a token name or literal. It causes the precedence of the grammar rule to become that of the following token
>   name or literal. For example, to make unary minus have the same precedence as multiplication the rules might resemble:

```
    %left  '+'  '-'
    %left  '*'  '/'

    %%

    expr    :       expr  '+'  expr
            |       expr  '-'  expr
            |       expr  '*'  expr
            |       expr  '/'  expr
            |       '-'  expr      %prec  '*'
            |       NAME
            ;
```